# Вопрос по конфигу PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

В примере на странице https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer в самом низу блока с e-mail адресами есть 2 адреса: addCC и addBCC - для чего они нужны?

```
//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляют к письму заголовки [`CC` и `BCC`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.3).

`CC` (`Carbon Copy`) - копия письма. Помимо адресата письмо будет отправлено по этим адресам. Получатель каждого из писем будет видеть полный список тех, кому письмо отправлялось.

`BCC` (`Blind Carbon Copy`) - скрытая копия письма. RFC описывает 3 возможных поведения:

- при подготовке письма к отправке из письма удаляется этот заголовок и рассылается помимо списков TO и CC по копии письма на каждый из указанных в этом заголовке адресов. Соответственно адресаты не видят, что это копия
- аналогично отправляются копии писем, но для отправки копий по списку BCC заголовок остаётся. Получатели из списков to и CC этот заголовок не получают, получатели из списка BCC соответственно видят весь список BCC
- получателям может быть отправлен пустой заголовок BCC, свидетельствующий о том, что кому-то были отправлены скрытые копии письма